# save scale data and recall data back into scale

Tags: python, load, tkinter, save

I need to create a code that will take 24 scale values and save them in a txt. file, i then want to be able to recall these values and put them back into the 24 scales. can someone point me in the right direction.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First read this :

http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#bltin-file-objects

then write some code and come back with concrete questions if necessary.